# Reformatting input-fields

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to reformat the contents of an HTML form-field when submitting.

For example: The user enters "`1.234,56`" (which is a valid format for numbers in this locale), but I want to submit the value "`1234.56`" to the server.

I'd like to hear about other peoples experience with this. How do you do this?

My first thought is an onSubmit-event, which reformats the contents. But does anyone has any experience with an implementation on this?

Or maybe a better idea?

---

Javascript is ALWAYS available. If it's much easier with Dojo, I can use that.

And by the way: It's actually a bit more complex, since I also want to reformat on "blur" too. So the user enters "`1234,56`" (input format). When focus changes, it should reformat to "`1.234,56`" (display format). But the actual value sent to the server should be "`1234.56`" (machine format).
Converting between input format and display format should be easy, but maybe all this can be combined in some clever way.

---

**EDIT:** This is not for a public website, so opinions about depending on Javascript and similar is not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Well, one idea that comes to mind may be to use Javascript exclusively, and store the actual entered value into a hidden field. Then trap the onBlur Javascript event of the textbox to call a function that formats values as per your requirement.

Finally, On form submission, access the value present in the hidden field, not the textbox.

Comment: I thought of this too. But this can double the size of input data. This can also be handled, but it doesn't seem very practical.

Answer (score 1):

Given the information, I would probably do the following:

The blur handler should

1. Get the input
2. Validate the input - is it a number?  is it within range?  etc.
3. Convert to normalized form for display (1.234,56)
4. Set the value of the form's [input] to the normalized form

The submit handler should

1. Get the input
2. Validate the input - same as above
3. Convert from locale-specific value to the value you want on the server.
4. Set the value of the form's [input] to the converted value.
5. Submit form.

Remember that no matter how much client-side validation you do, you still need to do server-side validation.  But I would do as much validation in Javascript as I could stand just because I prefer to let the user know his form values are going to fail without having to so to the server first.

Additionally, I would probably change the server-side action to be able to handle amounts in many locales.  That would give me a lot more wiggle room on the submit handler in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The way you asked the question, you basically want to validate on client side, which should be a no-go under any circumstances. Just submit the number and validate it server-side using locale-specific processing. If you want immediate feedback, use AJAX, but do the validation server-side -- you can do your onBlur() with an AJAX request.

Comment: I do not agree that clientside validation is a bad thing. Missing serverside validation is a bad thing, but that's another story. (And AJAX still contacts the server, what a waste.) 
And in this case it would be very practical to format it client-side.